# start navigating to position which is stored in database

Tags: android, database

I have an application where I am getting the latitude and longitude coordinates.

I want , when to press a button to start navigating to that position .

Now , I am storing latitude and longitude in database.

So , I want to extract the location first.When I press the button to navigate I open an alertdialog and in 'YES' I do:

```
public void navigation(final View v){



     AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt_bld.setMessage("Do you want to navigate to the saved position?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Navigate",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                        // Action for 'Yes' Button

                        String query = "SELECT latitude,longitude FROM MEMORIES ";
                        Cursor c1 = sqlHandler.selectQuery(query);

                        if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
                            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                                do {                
        String mylatitude=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
        String mylongitude=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("longitude"));

        Double lat=Double.parseDouble(mylatitude);
        Double lon=Double.parseDouble(mylongitude); 


                                    } while (c1.moveToNext());
                                }
                            }

                            c1.close();


            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + 
                    gps.getLocation().getLatitude() + "," + 
                    gps.getLocation().getLongitude() + "&daddr=" + mylatitude + "," + mylongitude ));
                    startActivity(intent);


                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // Action for 'NO' Button
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        // Title for AlertDialog
        alert.setTitle("Navigation");
        alert.show();

 }
```

I have the location stored (lat and lon) and i want to start navigating to that position.
How can I do that?

Thanks!

---------------------UPDATE-------------------------------------

If I do sth like:

```
    String mylat="";
String mylon="";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
...
public void navigation(final View v){
....
String mylatitude=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
String mylongitude=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("longitude"));


mylat=mylatitude;//stored coordinates from database 
mylon=mylongitude;

String f="45.08" //current location (start points)
String s="23.3";

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + 
f + "," + 
s + "&daddr=" + mylat + "," + mylon ));
startActivity(intent);
```

The intent starts and I am in the map application where the start points are the "f" and "s" I defined above but the destination points are 0.0 , 0.0 ;

So , I have 2 problems:

1) How to put to destination points  my stored locations (mylatitude ,mylongitude (which I copy to mylat,mylon)

2) How to get current location (initial points) because my gps class doesn't work on that.

Comment: Do You have to keep them as String in database? Better to store as two seperate float and make String if needed.

Comment: @Gustek:I'd prefer to keep them as String.But I am open to solutions.And generally I, I don't know if all this will work for navigating to the saved position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example below `ImplLocationService` is a class/service within my application that is providing the latitude and longitude coordinates of the current location within the device. The `Location` class is similar to Android's offering but is slightly different and is providing the destination latitude and longitude coordinates. If you were to pull these values from a database, the approach below is the same.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
               Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + 
               ImplLocationService.getCurrentLocation().getLatitude() + "," + 
               ImplLocationService.getCurrentLocation().getLongitude() + "&daddr=" + 
               location.getPoint().latitude + "," + location.getPoint().longitude));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: :First of all thanks for the help!So, instead of location.getPoint().latitude , I should put "lat" (as I have it above Double lat=Double.parseDouble(mylatitude);) , right?But lat and lon cannot be resolved as variables as I have it.I can't fihure how to do it..

Comment: @George You should be able to copy what I have and put in a fixed starting latitude and longitude location instead of my use of `ImplLocationService`. After doing that replace `location.getPoint().latitude` with your string values not double and that should do it. I'm not sure why your variables are not in scope, I would need to see all the code to determine that.

Comment: :I  updated.I put string values "mylatitude" and "mylongitude" but still cannot be resolved.

Comment: :With gps.getLocation().getLatitude() etc I call a service which finds the latitude and longitude.

Comment: Start with fixed latitude and longitude points, get the Intent working and then worry about pulling dynamic values. What is the error or what is happening that is not as you expect?

Comment: :Ok , it works!Just 2 things if you can.1) It shows me in the google maps "connection failed".What means?Also,can you point me to a service I can use in order to get users current location?Thanks!

Comment: @George You can use the LocationManager.         `mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mApplicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //grab the initial location so we do not return null out of the gates
        mCurrentLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        //register for updates so as the user moves we know where they are
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);` You'll note I have subscribed to events when the location changes.

Comment: :Because i am starting the intent which starts the navigation , so (if i am not wrong) it isn't necessary to use requestLocationUpdates ,right?Because I did it like:locationManager = (LocationManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Answer (score 1):

While storing the lat and long store it in this way...

```
String mylocation=latitude + ":" + longitude;
```

And while retriving it

```
String latitude = mylocation.subString(0, myLocation.indexOf(":") -  1 );
String longitude = mylocation.subString(myLocation.indexOf(":"));
```

and pass it as

```
j.putExtra("lon", longitude);
j.putExtra("lat", latitude);
```

Comment: Hello , the problem is that I need the location in another activity.I can't use mylocation.subString..Also, it is mylocation and not myLocation , right?

Comment: :Any ideas about that?Thanks!

Comment: bakriOnFire is right about this. If you wish to use it another activty , add it in intent and then in the second activity retrieve it from the intent and proceed as this answer.

Answer (score 1):

one possible way is to store your `latitude` and `longitude` values in shared preferences.

-To store values you can use

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

        Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString("mytext", text);
        editor.commit();
```

-and to retrive those values you can use

```
String value = prefs.getString("MyPrefs, "mytext");
```

in your code your are storing latitude and longitudes in double do not forget to convert them in `toString()`...

hope this helps

Comment: :Thanks but I am saving to database.